# PowerDNS caching NXDOMAIN for AAAA records, but there is a valid A record

Tags: dns, ipv6

I have a strange problem with PowerDNS. The initial problem described to me was that one HTTP request could be made to domains under `staging.corp`, but anything after that would fail with a DNS error.

I think I've discovered the issue, but I don't understand why it's happening, and if it's valid behaviour, or if I should file a bug with the PowerDNS folks.

The upstream DNS server is returning a valid A record, but an NXDOMAIN for the AAAA record. It seems like the first time the request is made, the valid A record is returned, but then the NXDOMAIN is cached afterwards, and any new requests immediately return NXDOMAIN.

Step 1: Confirm DNS is working

```
root:~# grep -v ^# /etc/powerdns/recursor.conf | grep -v ^$
etc-hosts-file=/etc/powerdns/hosts
export-etc-hosts=on
forward-zones-file=/etc/powerdns/recursor-forward-zones
local-port=53
quiet=yes
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns


root:~# cat /etc/powerdns/recursor-forward-zones
+staging.corp=10.100.251.99
+.=8.8.8.8
```

```
root:~# dig m.emu.staging.corp
 
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> m.emu.staging.corp
;; global options: +cmd                   
;; Got answer:                                            
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39857           
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
 
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:                               
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:                                                              
;m.emu.staging.corp.                IN      A
                       
;; ANSWER SECTION:                                                                                                                
m.emu.staging.corp. 6       IN      A       10.200.145.22

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 31 09:45:47 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

Step 2: Make the request

```
root:~# curl https://m.emu.staging.corp
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>   
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=https://mobile.emu.staging.corp">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Step 3: Check DNS again, note the **NXDOMAIN**

```
root:~# dig m.emu.staging.corp

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> m.emu.staging.corp
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 15030
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;m.emu.staging.corp.                IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
staging.corp.              165     IN      SOA     ns.corp. dns-admin.corp. 2022052303 10800 7200 2419200 3600

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 31 09:46:03 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

The upstream DNS server is responding with a valid A record:

```
root:~# dig @10.100.251.99 m.emu.staging.corp a

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> @10.100.251.99 m.emu.staging.corp a
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55158
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:  
;m.emu.staging.corp.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
m.emu.staging.corp. 10      IN      A       10.200.145.22

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 10.100.251.99#53(10.100.251.99)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 31 09:46:44 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

But NXDOMAIN for **AAAA**:

```
root:~# dig @10.100.251.99 m.emu.staging.corp aaaa

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.18-Ubuntu <<>> @10.100.251.99 m.emu.staging.corp aaaa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 10062
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;m.emu.staging.corp.                IN      AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
staging.corp.              1800    IN      SOA     ns.corp. dns-admin.corp 2022052303 10800 7200 2419200 3600

;; Query time: 109 msec
;; SERVER: 10.100.251.99#53(10.100.251.99)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 31 09:46:48 PDT 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 127
```

If I restart pdns-recursor, it works again for one request.

I can see a couple of options I can see to fix it:

1. Have the upstream DNS server respond without NXDOMAIN

If the upstream DNS server is behaving incorrectly, are there any RFCs that describe this behaviour? I haven't been able to find anything so far. I'd like to be able to point to some docs to say, "This is broken, here's why".

2. Change PowerDNS to drop the AAAA query

I haven't been able to find any docs on how to do this. This would have to be at a system level, the curl command I provided is just an example, the DNS queries could come from anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NXDOMAIN means that the name (and any name beneath it) does not exist. PowerDNS is therefore behaving correctly, and the authoritative DNS server is buggy.

Also see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8020.html